# Why text seemingly has padding when there's no padding nor margin?

Tags: html, css

I have an `h1` with no margin nor padding but there is still some white space above and under the content inside the `h1`.

[image]

Is it because of the font or is there something else ?
I tried setting `margin-block-start` and `margin-block-end` to `0` but nothing happened.

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

 html {
  font-size: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.accueil .container h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.accueil .container h3 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='accueil'>
  <div class='container'>
    <h1>SOMETHING</h1>
    <h3>something else</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the inspector, the "margin" (white space) you saw is actually the `content` part of the box-model of h1. So that's not because of `margin` or `padding`, it's because of the `font` itself. Try tweaking around with `line-height`, `font-size`,... etc to see if you get the result desired.

[image]

Comment: That's what I though. I tried with `width: fit-content`and `height: fit-content`and nothing changed.

Comment: As @Lalji Tadhani said in the comments below, `line-height: 0.7`works fine for me. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin for h1 or h3 like

```
  h1 {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 4.5rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin:0; /*Add This*/
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 2rem;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        margin-top:0;  /*Add This*/
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }
```

Comment: add screenshot here

Comment: add `line-height: 0.7;` for H1